# Android Studio - ¿Como agrandar o achicar una vista al deslizar horizontalmente?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, animación

**Descripción:**

Quiero lograr un text View que sea deslizable y agrandable. Es decir: Quiero que al deslizarlo desde la izquierda hacia la derecha se agrande hasta tener 100dp y que al deslizarlo desde la derecha hacia la izquierda, se encoja hasta tener 10dp.

**Adjunto un gráfico de como se vería lo que necesito:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Que puedo hacer para lograr esto?**

**Gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dices es algo casi imposible, tendría que sobre escribir el método `setOnTouchListener(...);` algo que no te  recomiendo..
Ya que tendrás cálculos realmente extremos..

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar un [NavegationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView) que se deslices hacia la derecha y en el agregar el TextView...

Comment: Cómo que imposible? No me parece nada complejo a pesar de que todavía no tenga los conocimientos para hacerlo. Se que hay que usar algunas animaciones y demás...

Comment: Dije casi imposible, si lo quieres hacer de todos modos, deberás  usar el método, serOnTouchListener(...);